# Development Virtual Machine - Is Windows XP still a possible option

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, license, legal

I want to separate my development work from my routine work. My host OS is Windows 7. I was wondering if Windows XP would be a viable choice for the guest OS. I do not own a copy of Windows XP now. Doing some quick searches on sites like Futureshop, I see that they don't sell Windows XP anymore.

I do not want to install Windows 7 as the guest OS (since it would take a significant amount of system resources).

Can I still buy Windows XP from a reputable source? (I do want it to be legal). Is there a reason it is not available anymore (I would have thought it would be available more at least for Virtual machine purposes - considering it is much lighter and provides the necessary base for Visual Studio, SQL Server etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why buy it? You can use [Windows XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) (MS Virtual PC) that can be downloaded free for Windows 7.

For further details on XP, see Microsoft's page " [Windows XP: The future](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-xp/end-of-sale.aspx) ".

Comment: Assuming his SKU of Windows 7 is Professional or higher.

Comment: Let's hope so. Personally I can't stand anything lower than professional after being babied by the Enterprise edition since it's release :)

Comment: Just note though you lose this option if you update to Windows 8 or 10.  Meaning you lose the XP license as well as the ability to run VirtualPC (replaced by the vastly superior but incompatible HyperV).

Answer (score 2):

Never done it myself, but it appears you can with an MSDN "MSDN Operating Systems" subscription. They list XP Home/Pro as available to you at that basic level.

All info is [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/subscriptionschart.aspx)